# Java Eclipse Create Heap-Dump on Breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints, heap-dump

How do I make a heapdump at a breakpoint in eclipse?

My Java program has 2 versions that do the same thing with 2 different methods.
One of these methods runs into a Heap Space Exception but the other doesn't.

I was able to get the heapdump for the one that encountered an error by setting the VM argument -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

For the program using the method that doesn't get the error, I want to get a heapdump at a certain breakpoint. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install Eclipse memory analyzer plug in
2. Set your debug point and start your application in debug mode and reach to the point where you would like to take Heap-Dump.
3. Go to Memory Analysis perspective (Once you install plug-in you will find this perspective)

[image: Memory Analysis Perspective]

4. Then click on Acquire Heap Dump button and you will get all head dumps till that debug point.

[image: Acquire Heap Dump]

Comment: I you have an empty list of local processes, try pressing Configure, select **HPROF jmap dump provider** and set the **-jdkhome** to your JDK installation directory (**NOT** the bin directory in it). Took me nearly an hour to find this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use jvisualvm to connect to the process then right-click and do a Heap Dump.